# How do I Create a WITS Connection in TCP / IP mode?

Tags: qt, tcp

I have an application developed under C ++, QT Creator, and QT , And now I want to create a WITS connection To transmit the data of my application to a server that receives data in WITS mode.
I never used this communication format, on the internet I do not find the documentation needed to create a WITS CONNECTION !.
may be someone can give me advice or idea , "how to create a WITS Connection under C++ , Qt creator and QT ".

attached a link to a WITS simulator

[Simulator WITS](https://info.erdosmiller.com/blog/wits-wellsite-information-transfer-specification-fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like pretty domain specific stuff. I'm not saying you won't get an answer, but you'll probably have to license a library or roll your own WITS code from scratch.

The Wikipedia page, which usually provides a useful starting point for things like this, only has the link you already posted. I found the actual specification here:

https://info.erdosmiller.com/blog/wits-wellsite-information-transfer-specification-fundamentals

and here's a summary:

https://onepetro.org/DC/article-abstract/4/04/291/76430/Wellsite-Information-Transfer-Specification-WITS?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Usually, when I develop an interface to an outside vendor, we have something called an Interface Requirements Document that specifies this stuff in detail, and we'll both work to make sure our software can communicate.

You should contact the entity you're sending data to and ask if they can provide code examples for packaging up WITS data for transmission.

Due to the small niche the drilling industry occupies in the IT world, it may be that you'll have to sit down with the raw specification and the simulator and work out your own WITS library. If you do manage to write one, make sure to set up a web site and offer to sell it for lots of money, because it looks to me like you'll be the first person to actually do so.

Comment: thank you for your response , i'm completly  agree with what you say.  
 i'm using an old  serveur used WITS " but i dont have any documentation that explane the WITS Protocole , on the forum , i have a response explain that   WITS can be transfered via TCP/IP or serial connection((e.g. QTcpSocket, QSerialPort) .  but i don't found any source or link to check this information and to check the general structure of the WITS protocol.